# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when using feed_dict in TensorFlow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to feed a Tensor containing the correct labels when I perform training.

The correct labels for the entire training dataset are contained in one tensor which has been converted from a numpy array:

```
numpy_label = np.zeros((614,5),dtype=np.float32)

for i  in range(614):
    numpy_label[i,label_numbers[i]-1] = 1

# Convert to tensor
y_label_all = tf.convert_to_tensor(numpy_label,dtype=tf.float32)
```

I have a placeholder for the correct labels for each batch:

```
images_per_batch = 5
y_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[images_per_batch,5])
```

During each training step, I slice the corresponding portion of `y_label_all` as `y_` and want to feed it as `y_label`:

```
for step in range(100):

    # Slice correct labels for current batch
    y_ = tf.slice(y_label_all,[step,0],[images_per_batch,5])

    # Train
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_step,loss],feed_dict={y_label:y_})
```

**This generates the error:**

```
_, loss_value = sess.run([train_step,loss],feed_dict={y_label:y_})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 357, in run
np_val = np.array(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_t.dtype.as_numpy_dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**Shape of variables `y_` and `y_label`:**

```py
#y_: 
Tensor("Slice:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(5), Dimension(5)]), dtype=float32)

#y_label: 
Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(5), Dimension(5)]), dtype=float32)
```

I don't understand what is going wrong? Apparently it is something to do with the numpy - but now that I have converted the numpy array to a tensor, does that affect anything?

Help and insight are much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: We had some missing documentation to specify type of "value", should be fixed in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that that `feed_dict` must be compatible with numpy arrays.

Your code results in something like this

`np.array(<tf.Tensor 'Slice_5:0' shape=(5, 5) dtype=float32>, dtype=np.float32)`

Which fails in numpy with cryptic error above. To fix it, you need to convert your Tensor to numpy, something like below

```
for step in range(100):

    # Slice correct labels for current batch
    y_ = tf.slice(y_label_all,[step,0],[images_per_batch,5])
    y0 = sess.run([y_])

    # Train
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_step,loss],feed_dict={y_label:y0})
```

Comment: One observation: if you put a call to `tf.slice()` in the training loop, the performance can be surprisingly poor, because it adds nodes to the graph in each iteration. Instead, you should define a single `tf.placeholder()` for the current step, a single `tf.slice()` in terms of that placeholder, and feed in the value for the step (instead of the label data, which is already in the graph) in each iteration.

Comment: @mrry about that....wondering if we should just make that use-case fast rather than making the users think harder about refactoring things with placeholders

Comment: @mrry Thank you! Yes, it does seem to be running a bit slow. However, I don't understand what you mean by "... a single `tf.slice()` in terms of that placeholder, and feed in the value for the step (instead of the label data, which is already in the graph) in each iteration." Could you please elaborate on that?